# Some questions about the Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

there are some questions about the Array when I read the **The C++ programming Language(special 3rd Edition).**

In the **Section 5.3.1 Navigating Arrays**:

```
void fi(char v[])
{
    for(int i = 0 ; v[i] != 0; i++) use v[i];
}
```

Que 1: The statement **v[i] != 0** is just fit for the char type, right ?

```
void f(int i)
{
    int v[i];
    cout << v[0] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    f(10);
    return 0;
}
```

As I know, the **i** must be the const value in **v[i]**, but the upper code snippet runs right without error on g++ 4.4.3.

Que 2: How to explain the case ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1:** `v[i] == 0` is a special test to check for the `null terminator character`, `\0` at the end of C-style strings (char arrays). In C++, this is how char arrays work:

```
char word[] = "dog";
//Index: d-0, o-1, g-2, \0-3 \0 is a special char that signal string end
```

`0` is the integer ascii code for the null termination char, `i != 0`, checks that the data is valid.

**Q2:** You're lucky, `G++` supports [variable size arrays](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Comment: Q1: I tested int array, if I init the array like this: int v[] = {0, 0, 0};  It will only output 0.   Thanks.

Comment: Only for `char` arrays